# Keras LSTM input incompatible with layer, expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying out embedding with LSTM and have the following in Keras:

```
inp = Input(shape=(20, 1))
x = Embedding(total_words, 256)(inp)
x = LSTM(128)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation ='softmax')(x)
```

However, I don't understand why I keep getting the following error at the line `x = LSTM(128)(x)`:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

What have I missed out?

Comment: Try with `shape=(20,)`

Comment: That is because the output of `Embeddings` is of shape `(None, 20, 1, 256)`, but the LSTM layer is expecting `(None, Timesteps, Features)` or `(None, 20, 256)`, @DanielMöller is right, you need to reshape your input.

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes @DanielMöller Sorry if I sound silly, I'm fairly new to this. I've tried having the input shape as `Input(shape=(20,0))` but this doesn't work too. If the Embeddings layer is outputting `(None, 20, 1, 256)`, I'm still not sure how can I reshape it to `(None, 20, 256)` for the LSTM layer?

Comment: `inp = Input(shape=(20,))` should be enough, or you can instead add a Reshape layer after the input

Comment: did you set x as the first layer in compile?

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes 's answer should be marked as the correct answer and perhaps elaborated on. For anyone else looking at this, drop the 1 from the `(20, 1)` -> `(20,)`

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes How do I solve it if my input dimensions are of the shape `(N,50)`, where each training input has sequence length = 50 and this input is going into the embedding layer.

Comment: @KPMG It's been a while from this answer and the last time I used Keras, but I would say `inp = Input(shape=(50,))` is your case